# How to change line style for different regression lines in seaborn implot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to change the line style in seaborn implot. I know that we can do the following for changing line style for one regression line.

```
sns.lmplot(x='xx' , data=dataset, y='yy',line_kws={'ls':'--'})
```

But what about using hue in implot, when we have three regression line for example:

```
 sns.lmplot(x='xx' , data=dataset, y='yy',hue='class', markers=["o", "x", "D"])
```

How can we do that? How can we change the line style of each regression line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think you can :( Here's a workaround that looks similar to [lmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) but uses [regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) in order to control the individual linestyles:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

_, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
for d, m, ls in zip(tips["day"].unique(), ["o", "x", ".", "D"], ["--", ":", "-.", "-"]):
    sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips.loc[tips.day == d], marker=m, line_kws={"ls":ls}, ax=ax, label=d)
plt.legend()
```

[image]